# ¿Cómo puedo saber las exceptions que mi código puede generar?

Tags: java, excepciones

Estaba trabajando en Java, y me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de saber todas las exceptions que puede generar mi programa, para así confirmar si las estoy tratando todas o no.

Comment: buenas MrAlbertus, bienvenido. quieres una **lista** de todas las que te pueden dar?

Comment: Si claro estaría muy agradecido

Comment: El problema es que no es así como funciona este sitio. No es un foro y las preguntas son generalmente relacionadas con fallos en código. Hay muchos tipos de excepciones y las puedes ver en la documentacion de Java. Aqui no te podemos dar respuesta a eso. Te recomiendo que visites el Tour y el Centro de ayuda para saber que preguntas son validas en este sitio . Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero creo que no has entendido mi pregunta, tan solo quería saber si hay algun método para mostrar todas las exceptions  que pueda generar mi programa no quería una lista de ellas, deduzco por tu comentario que la respuesta es "no", la brevedad en una respuesta también es muy bien vista, igualmente gracias por tu aportación.

Comment: No creo que sea posible lo que pides.

Comment: Gracias por aclararme la duda sstan, supongo que con la documentacion será suficiente.

Comment: Hay que diferenciar, Posibles excepciones no controlados (unchecked) no se pueden analizar facilmente, normalmente hay demasiados posibilidades como podrían ocurrir. Otros Excepciones que hay que declarar explicitamente con `throws` no puedes olvidar de tratar, porque tu IDE te los va reclamar si no lo tratas. Si tienes acceso a todo el código fuente, existe por lo menos la posibiidad de comprobar una gran mayoría de excepciones que se pueden revisar. Sería posible de darte más pistas que se puede hacer y que no en una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, creo que tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Yo cuando quiero saber todas las excepciones, utilizo el siguiente código

```
 try{
        //Tu código
    }catch(Throwable e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());//Y aquí te imprime el error capturado
        // O puedes poner la línea de arriba o si solo quieres mostrar un mensaje pues..
        System.out.println("Error en la ejecución");
    }
```

Con esto tratas todas las excepciones que puede causar el programa. Pero también hay excepciones que tratan solo una parte.

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre *saber* y *atrapar* todas las excepciones. Si esto es lo que significaba la pregunta, entonces la pregunta no era clara.

Comment: esto no "da todas las excepciones que puedan darse" solo las que fallan en ese momento. y ten en cuenta que hay excepciones que solo se dan una vez ejecutando el codigo y bajo ciertas circunstancias (ej: introducir un numero y pasar un string alfabetico, no se puede operar matematicamente por ejemplo)

Comment: Te lo agradezco, me sirve para lo que andaba buscando

Comment: He editado la respuesta. El que captura todas la excepciones es Throwable, por debajo de él están Error y Exception. Aquí te dejo un enlace con la explicación de el tipo de excepciones en java http://www.davidmarco.es/articulo/tratamiento-de-excepciones-en-java

Comment: Si se sienten muy buenos para criticar una respuesta, entonces respondan algo que supere lo que @barraca96 está proponiendo al **preguntador** ¬¬

Comment: Eso se podría si la pregunta no estuviera cerrada, @MáximaAlekz